# Issues when attempting to compile AspectJ tutorial application

Tags: java, aspectj

I was trying to follow this tutorial:

http://andrewclement.blogspot.pt/2009/02/load-time-weaving-basics.html

but I stumbled across a couple of problems:

To start with, my system didn't have the `javac` and `ajc` PATH variables set, so I added the `bin/` directory of my JDK7 to the PATH variable, as well as AspectJ's `bin/` directory.

But when running `ajc WhereDoesTheTimeGo.java Simple.java` I got the following error:

```
[warning] couldn't find aspectjrt.jar on classpath, checked: C:\Program Files\Ja
va\jre7\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files
\Java\jre7\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program
 Files\Java\jre7\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Prog
ram Files\Java\jre7\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\classes;C:\Program Fi
les\Java\jre7\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\dn
sns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre
7\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program
 Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\
sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java
\jre7\lib\tools.jar

[error] classpath error: unable to find org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint (check that a
spectjrt.jar is in your classpath)
```

so I manually added the referred file to the classpath:

```
ajc -cp ajc -cp C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjrt.jar Simple.java WhereDoesTheTimeGo.java
```

and then execution went apparently alright, being both .class files created. 
But then...:

```
ajtests>java Simple
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/Sign
ature
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.lang.Signature
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

so I once again added AspectJ's jars to the classpath:

```
java -cp C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjrt.jar;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjtools.jar;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjweaver.jar;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\org.aspectj.matcher.jar Simple
```

But that will only yield

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Simple
```

What's going wrong here? Why is this giving me so much pain than what the tutorials would make me believe I'd have to have?

### EDIT

I've noticed I only have to write

```
aj -cp .;;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjweaver.jar Simple
```

and that will work. What I'm finding strange is that `aspectjweaver.jar` seems to be already being passed on by the `aj` script:

```
@echo off
REM This file generated by AspectJ installer
REM Created on Tue Apr 16 19:02:36 BST 2013 by top_secret

if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
if "%ASPECTJ_HOME%" == "" set ASPECTJ_HOME=c:\aspectj1.7

if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe" goto haveJava
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.bat" goto haveJava
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" goto haveJava
echo java does not exist as %JAVA_HOME%\bin\java
echo please fix the JAVA_HOME environment variable
:haveJava
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -classpath "%ASPECTJ_HOME%\lib\aspectjweaver.jar" "-Djava.system.class.loader=org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.WeavingURLClassLoader" "-Daj.class.path=%ASPECTPATH%;%CLASSPATH%" "-Daj.aspect.path=%ASPECTPATH%" %*
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this instead, for your java command:

```
java -cp .;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjrt.jar;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjtools.jar;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\aspectjweaver.jar;C:\aspectj1.7\lib\org.aspectj.matcher.jar Simple
```

You need to include the current directory (where you are compiling your source files to) in the classpath.

Comment: One more thing. Any clue on whether the code I see around doesn't need all this complications and I do, on this machine?

Comment: More than likely the author has both the current directory (.) and AspectJ JARS permanently added to their CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Yes. Having the AspectJ's jar files in the CLASSPATH environment variables did it. Thx